# Vaadin: Remove caption from menu item

Tags: java, vaadin, menubar, caption, vaadin8

i have a menu bar with some items.i want each item to display only it's icon.so how can i remove caption from each item?
this is what i have:

```
MenuBar actionBar = new MenuBar();
menuBar.addItem(translator.getString("home"),VaadinIcons.HOME,(selectedItem) 
-> getUI().home());
MenuItem user= menuBar.addItem(AspirinSession.getCurrent().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(), 
VaadinIcons.MENU, null);
menuBar.addStyleName(ValoTheme.MENUBAR_BORDERLESS);
```

[image]

Comment: How about passing null as the first parameter (caption) of `addItem`?

Comment: thanks, but caption can't be null(gives error) @Thibstars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do a *setCaption("")* on the buttons or do not add a caption in the fist place:

```
menuBar.addItem("", VaadinIcons.HOME ,(selectedItem) -> getUI().home());
MenuItem user= menuBar.addItem("", VaadinIcons.MENU, null);
```

That should do the trick.

You can play around with buttons on  their [demo page](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/interaction/button) (hit the "edit" on the right). Or maybe check their CSS approach [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-button.html), that would still allow you to add text to a button.